# Move a set of points to different destinations with the minimum distance variance

Tags: algorithm, location, position, minimum, variance

The goal is to join the stars with the blue dots in a way that the variance between the travelling distances is minimal. In some cases (if not all) the solution can also avoid overlapping between the paths of the stars to a blue dot. Scenario 1D shows the sequence that must be followed with the solution, where it shows that the star and blue dot pairs formed must be 1A and 2B. The red arrow indicates a solution with higher distance variance, while the black arrow shows the minimum distance variance. The same occurs in the scenario 2D, where the pairs to be formed will be 1A, 2B and 3C. I brute force solution that I wrote considers all the possible pair (star + blue dots) combinations, and then select the set of combinations with the minimum travelling distance variance.

[image: Problem description]

Comment: Looks like any heuristic would already get a pretty good result. Start with the translation that maps the center of mass of stars to the center of mass of blue dots. Then refine.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a bipartite matching algorithm to match the stars and the dots at the minimum total cost. Define the cost of each star-dot combination as the *square* of the traveling distance between them. That makes the optimal matching the one with the lowest total variance.